# Test if computer is available on network

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, ping

I work on a company which has many Shop. Each shop has his own IP address :
SHOP 1 = 192.168.1.0/24, SHOP 2 = 192.168.2.0/24, SHOP 3 = 192.168.3.0/24, etc...

I have a number of Windows computers (between 1 and 9) on the same subnet (255.255.255.0) on each shop.
Each computer has a static IP address : 1st = 192.168.1.10, 2nd = 192.168.1.20, 3rd = 192.168.1.30, 4th = 192.168.1.40, etc.

The HQ of my company can deploy softs ONLY on the first computer on each shop (licences issue).
Here, we will try to install Xerox drivers on ALL windows computer on all shop.

I made 3 batch script :

1. The first, launched as the superadmin of the computer, install a new user with admin rights to install drivers
2. The second, launched as the new user, install Xerox drivers and set as default the printer.
3. The third, launched as the superadmin of the computer, try to install Xerox drivers on other computers of the same shop :

   - Loop over my 9 ip address `(for /l %%G in (...) do (...)`
   - For each IP address, test if it ping.
   - Do a ftp transfer between the computer 1 and the IP address (drivers packages + scripts)
   - PsExec64.exe to run the first script
   - PsExec64.exe to run the second script

The first and the second script works perfectly, we'll not speak about them.

Where I need help is on the thrid.

I try 3 scripts :

The first :

```
set subnet=192.168.1.
for /L %%G in (20, 10, 90) do (
    ping -n 1 %subnet%%%G | findstr "TTL="
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo Ping %subnet%%%G : OK >> log_ping_errorlevel.txt
    ) else (
        echo Ping %subnet%%%G : KO >> log_ping_errorlevel.txt
    )
)
```

Here the log_ping_errorlevel.txt with 2 computers on my subnet :

```
Ping 192.168.1.20 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.30 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.40 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.50 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.60 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.70 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.80 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.90 : OK`
```

I tried to surround %errorlevel% and 0 by simple quote but I get the same result.

Here an extract of the output if I run the batch in cmd window :

```
C:\Temp\Xerox_Install>(
ping -n 1 192.168.1.90   | findstr "TTL="
if '0'=='0' (echo "Ping 192.168.1.90 : OK"  1>>log_ping_errorlevel.txt )    el
se (echo "Ping 192.168.1.90 : KO"  1>>log_ping_errorlevel.txt ) 
)
```

It seems that the errorlevel is always = 0 in my script, IDK why.

The second :

```
set subnet=192.168.1.
for /L %%G in (20, 10, 90) do (
    ping -n 1 %subnet%%%G && set pingtest=ok
    if '%ping_test%'=='ok' (
        echo Ping %subnet%%%G : OK >> log_ping_errorlevel.txt
    ) else (
        echo Ping %subnet%%%G : KO >> log_ping_errorlevel.txt
    )
)
```

Here the log_ping_set.txt with 2 computers on my subnet :

```
Ping 192.168.1.20 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.30 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.40 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.50 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.60 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.70 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.80 : OK
Ping 192.168.1.90 : OK`
```

I think the ping command result is always 0 then the setter pingtest can be executed.

The third :

Because I'm stuck with the ping command, I tried the if exist folder on remote computer :

```
set subnet=192.168.1.
for /L %%G in (20, 10, 90) do (
    if exist \\%subnet%%%G\C$\Temp\ (
        echo Remote folder reachable >> log_folder_reachable.txt
    ) else (
        echo ERROR 404 - Remote folder not found >> log_folder_reachable.txt
    )
)
```

Here the log_folder_reachable.txt with 2 computers on my subnet :

```
Remote folder reachable
ERROR 404 - Remote folder not found
ERROR 404 - Remote folder not found
ERROR 404 - Remote folder not found
ERROR 404 - Remote folder not found
ERROR 404 - Remote folder not found
ERROR 404 - Remote folder not found
ERROR 404 - Remote folder not found
```

It works BUT the if exist timeover is about 160 seconds and I don't want to wait for 160 seconds before going to the next computer...

Can someone help me with any method but not using external tools ?

Comment: When you are inside a parenthesized code block, you need to enable delayed expansion and reference your variables like this.  Example: `%errorlevel%` becomes `!errorlevel!`.

Comment: I tried but IDK why, the batch not recognized the var !errorlevel! even if i `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. Thx for your answer, Magoo found me the solution !

Comment: If you continue to use batch files at some point you will need to use Delayed Expansion.  Even Magoo pointed that out to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read SO items about `delayedexpansion`.

```
if %errorlevel%==0 (
```

in the first script should be

```
if not errorlevel 1 (
```

[obviously, reverse the logical condition and remove the "not"]

`if errorlevel 1` means "if `errorlevel` is 1 **or greater than 1**" and is interpreted on the *run-time* value of `errorlevel`.

Next:

```
ping -n 1 %subnet%%%G && set pingtest=ok
if '%ping_test%'=='ok' (
```

should be

```
set "ping_test="
ping -n 1 %subnet%%%G && set "ping_test=ok"
if defined ping_test (
```

Notes 
you are setting `pingtest` in your `ping` command, then you are attempting to test `ping_test`

Even had the variablename been correct, the purpose for the quotes in an `if` statement is to combine the contents as a single string. Single-quotes don't cut the mustard, double-quotes are required.

With the code you have, `ping_test` once set will retain its value for the next loop, you need to *clear* it before the`ping`.

The replacement code first sets the value of `ping_test` to *nothing*. The quotes delimit the variable name and value so that trailing spaces on the line are *not* included in the value assigned. The `ping` command then may set the value of `ping_test` to (ok, but any value other than *nothing* (ie *something*) is valid). The `if defined` command interprets the *run-time* value of the variable.

The third part - well, getting desperate, but no need to go this far as the changes I've outlined should solve the problem.

Comment: I kept the script 1 and used the `if not errorlevel 1` and everything works great ! Thx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your first set of code where you said you tried to use delayed expansion it should look like this. Tested and works on my network.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set subnet=192.168.1.
for /L %%G in (20, 10, 90) do (
    ping -n 1 %subnet%%%G | findstr "TTL="
    if !errorlevel!==0 (
        echo Ping %subnet%%%G : OK >> log_ping_errorlevel.txt
    ) else (
        echo Ping %subnet%%%G : KO >> log_ping_errorlevel.txt
    )
```

Comment: Now I read your code, i'm pretty sure that my error was to `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` inside the for loop...

Comment: @locobastos you can put it inside the DO execution.